# Хвилюватись чи переживати?

Tags: вживання-слів

Завжди думала, що правильно вживати "хвилюватись", а нещодавно натрапила на статтю, де пише, що це русизм і краще використовувати "переживати". http://tereveni.org/topic/20910/ тут думки теж дуже різні. То як правильно?

Comment: вітаємо на українському stack exchange, на цьому сайті заохочується самостійна перевірка фактів перед написанням питань. сходіть до кількох словників, будь ласка, почитайте визначення для обох слів, зробіть попередні висновки, поділіться ними з нами, якщо самостійно не розберетеся. якщо зробите це і все одно не будете впевнені у тому, яке слово вживати, приходьте, редаґуйте своє питання, ми допоможемо. відредаґуєте питання - зніму свій мінус.

Answer (score 2):

В Академічному тлумачному словнику (1970-1980) присутні наступні визначення:

> ***[ХВИЛЮВАТИСЯ](http://sum.in.ua/s/khvyljuvatysja)*** - Бути збудженим, занепокоєним; турбуватися. *Бекір хвилювався, заїкався і червонів* (Михайло Коцюбинський, II, 1955, 140); *Іван Тимофійович хвилювався, в нього тремтіли руки, хотів
>   запалити, розминав цигарки, але вони ламалися* (Юрій Мушкетик, День..,
>   1967, 171).
>
> ***[ПЕРЕЖИВАТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/perezhyvaty)*** - Жити довше, ніж хто-, що-небудь, після смерті кого-небудь або загибелі когось, чогось. *Ніхто не може світа
>   пережити* (Номис, 1864, № 389)

Згідно із Російсько-українськи народним сучасним словником 2009–

> 3) (за кого, что) непокоїтися, тривожитися, турбуватися, (волноваться)
>   ***хвилюватися***, вболівати (уболівати), (опасаться за кого) потерпати;

На мою думку, більш правильно вживати слово ***"хвилюватися"***, адже ***"переживати"*** має зовсім інше значення.